# Proper way of updating the contents of a QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qcombobox

I have a [QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) that is a selector for available serial ports. I want to update this combobox whenever a new user interaction with element starts but I have a couple of problems.  Normally when it is clicked or messed with by keyboard, no signals exist to know when it is clicked or otherwise the focus of a user. A close approximation is the `void mainwindow::on_comboBox_highlighted(const QString &arg1)` slot but this receives a signal every time the option under the cursor changes, not just when the form initially receives focus. This is problematic because if I erase the contents of the list and repopulate the contents of the list, the method will immediately be called again and multiple instances of the method will run and try to do opposite things indefinitely (race condition) unless some sort of state consideration is implemented in the method.

Sometimes items may disappear from the list on update because they are no longer available to the system. For this reason, it is desirable to just erase and repopulate the entire list on update instead of detecting unavailable items and removing them and then adding new items not already found in the list. The trouble is that even with state consideration, doing this will deselect whatever item is under the mouse cursor and retrigger the update.

An example naive approach that would create a race condition could be:

```
void mainwindow::on_comboBox_highlighted(const QString &arg1)
{
    delete port;
    ui->comboBox->clear();
    for (int i=0;i<QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts().length();i++){
        const QString comport=QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()[i].portName();
        ui->comboBox->addItem(comport);
    }
    port = openport(getport());
}
```

**What is a way of detecting interaction with and updating a combobox without creating a race condition?**

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals

Comment: @scopchanov That is a way of blocking signals but I already have that. The problem still remains that there is no good way of detecting the start of a user interaction generically.

Comment: Did you block them in the `on_comboBox_highlighted` slot or outside?

Comment: They were blocked at the start of on_comboBox_highlighted and unblocked at the end. This stopped it from trying to erase and write to the list at the same time but it still updates every time the item hovered over changes and it leaves the item under the mouse unhighlighted at the end of operation. It also doesn't work if the interaction is invoked by keyboard instead of mouse.

Comment: @amoose136 I have a suggestion, because do not create a thread that is continuously checking the ports and every time they change send the new ports, so you avoid the inconveniences.

Comment: @amoose136 Another suggestion is to use the focusInEvent event, but keep in mind that this is triggered each time the mouse enters the widget, for this you must create a subclass of QComboBox.

Comment: @amoose136 Another option is to use eventFilter () and filter the QEvent :: FocusIn event and be issued by the QComboBox object.

Comment: Because QSerialPortInfo doesn't have any signals, you could install an event filter on the QComboBox and watch for its ShowEvent and then update the list.

Comment: @scopchanov It's still not that simple because sometimes the field could be highlighted and moved through with the arrow keys. In this case ShowEvent signal is not sent.

Comment: Then go with focusIn as eyllanesc suggested.